# Clang error "implicit instantiation of undefined template std::tuple_size<auto>"

Tags: c++, c++20, clang++

#### Is there a (clean) work-around to Clang's behavior "undefined template smthg<auto>" ?

Code example :

- https://godbolt.org/z/GGs7ndKE4 (see below for copy/paste)

Additional insight :

- This issue is **not** reproductible with **GCC** nor **MSVC/CL**,
  thus only affect **clang** and **clang-cl**
- Clang-cl add the following error message :

  ```
    error : cannot mangle this 'auto' type yet
  ```

What I'd expect is that, according the example provided above, to get respectively two types with the same - *evaluatable* -  `std::tuple_size_v` :

```cpp
class std::tuple<
   struct std::integral_constant<bool,0>,
   struct std::integral_constant<bool,1>,
   struct std::integral_constant<bool,0>
>
class std::tuple<bool,bool,bool>
```

Am I missing a point?

Code example :

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename> class trait, typename... Ts>
struct trait_result {

    template <template <typename...> class T>
    using as_t = T<typename trait<Ts>::type...>;
    template <template <typename...> class T>
    constexpr static auto as_v = T{trait<Ts>::value...};
    using as_tuple_t = as_t<std::tuple>;
    constexpr static auto as_tuple_v = std::tuple{trait<Ts>::value...};
};

namespace test
{
    template <typename T>
    using is_int = std::is_same<int, T>;
    using results = trait_result<is_int, char, int, bool>;

    using results_as_tuple = results::as_t<std::tuple>; // ok
    using results_as_tuple_value_type = std::decay_t<decltype(results::as_v<std::tuple>)>; // ko

    static_assert(std::tuple_size_v<results_as_tuple> == std::tuple_size_v<results_as_tuple_value_type>);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Yakk - Adam Nevraumont](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk-adam-nevraumont), and as conclusion, here is the way I fixed it :

```cpp
using as_array_t = std::array<std::tuple_element_t<0, decltype(std::tuple{trait<Ts>::value...})>, sizeof...(Ts)>;
constexpr static inline auto as_array_v = as_array_t{trait<Ts>::value...};
```

This avoid another `#if __clang__ /* workaround on clang ICE ... */` in the codebase

[EDIT] For completeness purpose :

- Even if the code above fixed compilation for Clang, it did not for Clang-CL. The following code still failed to compile, with the same error message.

```cpp
template <typename T>
using is_int = std::is_same<int, T>;
using results = trait_result<is_int, char, int, bool>;

using results_as_tuple = results::as_t<std::tuple>;
using results_as_tuple_value_type = std::decay_t<decltype(results::as_v<std::tuple>)>; // error here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template <template <typename...> class T>
constexpr static auto as_v = T{trait<Ts>::value...};
```

this attempts to use the deduction guide of `T` to generate a type.

If you write

```
auto as_v = results::as_v<std::tuple>;
```

the compiler crashes, even before the rest of your work.

Assuming you are willing to do without the deduction guide:

```
template <template <typename...> class T>
constexpr static T<decltype(trait<Ts>::value)...> as_v = {trait<Ts>::value...};
```

makes the rest of the code compile.

Now,

```
template <template <typename...> class T>
constexpr static auto as_v = T<decltype(trait<Ts>::value)...>{trait<Ts>::value...};
```

also doesn't compile when you type

```
auto as_v = results::as_v<std::tuple>;
```

so it might not be the deduction guide that is the problem, but rather `constexpr static auto` here.

This outside of the class:

```
template<template<class...>class T, template<class>class trait, class...Ts>
constexpr auto foo = T{trait<Ts>::value...};
```

together with this inside the class:

```
template <template <typename...> class T>
constexpr static decltype(foo<T, trait, Ts...>) as_v = foo<T, trait, Ts...>;
```

gives you deduction guides and no internal compiler errors.

Comment: Theses explorations results you provide in your answer are really interesting, and I'd like to thank you about it.  
However, I still wonder what is the root-cause of this compiler (understand clang) behavior, in opposition to GCC and Msvc's.  

Perhaps if any reader who now the standard better than I do, might pin-point the paper that best describe what the expected behavior should be !

Comment: @guss a complier crash is a bug regardless; you can report it to clang developers?

Comment: What makes you think this is ICE ? To me, this is a regular, handled error, from the compiler's perspective

Comment: About Clang-CL, my (crazy) guess is the it uses mangled informations when deducing the syntaxe :
```cpp
template <template <typename...> class T>
constexpr static auto as_v = T{trait<Ts>::value...};
```
when `T = std::tuple`

Which cause the `error : cannot mangle this 'auto' type yet` error, before ` implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::tuple_size<auto>'`

Comment: I filed a bug report on LLVM : https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49747

Comment: @guss 2nd code block in my answer crashes compiler; it is a subexpression of your bug.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the ICE you're mentionning, which is strange. However, Clang looks stuck when attempting to compile this : https://godbolt.org/z/b9GrnMPbn which is strange enough to create a bug report